# Is it possible to deploy an app developed using .net mobile in ordinary GSM phones?

Tags: .net, mobile-application

I heard about developing mobile applications with an extension to the .NET Framework, called the Microsoft Mobile Internet Toolkit (MMIT) .Is it possible to deploy it in GSM/GPS based basic phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MMIT is more or less about controls. For a .net application to run on any device you need some version of CLR on it. It is not possible on just any GSM phone.

However there are many phones based on Windows Mobile OS and now Windows Phone 7 which should be able to support .net application natively. Though only subset of .net APIs are available on those mobile devices.